# Database design using UML Class Diagram

Tags: database, database-design, uml

I would like to design a database using UML class diagrams but I dont know how. Can someone help me. How can I design a database using UML class diagrams?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UML class diagram for database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231096/uml-class-diagram-for-database)

Answer (score 26):

Making an SQL database model in the form of a UML class diagram from a general information design model essentially requires to

1. Represent all entity types (or better: classes representing object types) as classes stereotyped as «object table» using SQL datatype names and replacing the UML `{id}` property modifier with a «pkey» stereotype:

   [image]
2. Eliminate enumeration attributes for DBMS that do not support enumerations by connecting the object table with a corresponding enum table via a foreign key dependency arrow (a UML dependency stereotyped «fkey»):
   [image]
   Otherwise, as in the case of MySQL, you can use their syntax in the model like so:
   [image]
3. Eliminate multi-valued attributes:

   [image]
4. Eliminate associations:

   1. Replace any functional association with a foreign key dependency:
      [image]
   2. Replace any many-to-many association (relationship type) with a class stereotyped as «association table» and two foreign key dependencies:
      [image]
5. Eliminate generalization/inheritance relationships:

   [image]

See [this book chapter](https://web-engineering.info/book/InformationManagement/MakingTableModels.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

you may try to start with a UML class diagram. Maybe you can find this tutorial useful - http://argouml-db.tigris.org/documentation/DB_UML_Guide.htm

Comment: great link - I found that tutorial very useful

Answer (score 1):

You can additionally use "Relation scheme diagram" to design table relationship and clearly represent primary key / foreign key dependencies.

see this [tutorial](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php).