# How to model a hierarchy of (sub)categories in a Class Diagram and in an SQL Table Model?

Tags: sql, database-design, uml, class-diagram

Someone could help me please?

I want to make a class diagram in UML, and I have CATEGORY class which can have SUBCATEGORIES and so on. How can I manage it in class diagram, thus in mysql database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you think a "category" is?

Comment: CATEGORY is a class

Comment: So, please edit your question.

Comment: Well, capitalizing the word doesn't change anything.

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem. I have a class diagram which contains a CATEGORY table. And that table may have(or not) subcategories, which can have also subcategories, and so on. I would like to know how I can do that with UML.

Comment: And I just don't understand what you're talking about. Maybe you can illustrate your problem.

Comment: I can't post images. I have not rights, unfortunately

Comment: Place an image on a public server and we can put it in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS This is also too broad. PS Clarify via edits, not comments. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)  Use images only to augment text.

Comment: @philipxy: Before you throw a ton of intimidating remarks on a new contributor, please try to stick to the point and express yourself in a clear manner using simple and correct English. PS This question is not too broad. It's a precise question about a recurrent modeling problem.

Comment: @philipxy: This is not a duplicate of the post you mentioned, which is about relational implementations of hierarchies, but not about information/class modeling.

Comment: @GerdWagner Class & type hierarchies are just special cases of hierarchies.

Comment: This is not clear. If you want to do something in UML what is the SQL & database-design tags for? What does "thus" mean.  Please use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for my poor english. I will speak on french next time. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hierarchy (or tree) of categories is modeled with a recursive one-to-many association, which  associates the `Category` class with itself, as shown in the following diagram:

[image]

Such an *Information Design Model* can be transformed into an *OOP Class Model* and into an *SQL Table Model*, like so:

[image]

Notice how the `superCategory` column is designated as a foreign key referencing the `categories` table in the table model: by a UML dependency arrow stereotyped as «fk».

I hope you can figure out yourself how to code the SQL Table Model in an SQL `Create Table` statement.

p.s.: For more about how to model databases with UML CLass Diagrams seee https://stackoverflow.com/a/21394401/2795909

Comment: Uh, that was what he meant :-o

Comment: Thank you for modeling the hierrarchy. But in data model, it is a little bit confused for me with. Let consider that we have a CATEGORY(id, name). According to the one-to-many association, the subcategory will have foreign key, that is id of the father. But what about the sub category of the subcategory? What will be its foreign key? Thanks a lot for the diagram :)

Comment: I've extended my answer for explaining how to get the corresponding database design.

Comment: Sort @Gerd Wagner. I am a newbie with satckoverflow. I chopé have marked as "solved". Thank you very much.