# How to draw this database model?

Tags: database

I have to draw a database model to store data for Customer and Customer's address. Database model needs to satisfy following requirements:

- Table can contain example columns
- Database model should support selection of the preferred address
- Database model should support marking address as unused

Does someone have an idea how to draw it?

Comment: Are you asking for a software that allows you to graphically display the DB model you design with the described features? If so, the question may be a better fit on [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in question. I want to someone help me out how to draw it.

Comment: I'm sorry, the focus of the question is still not quite clear to me: Do you have a database model (in mind, on paper, ...) and you're asking about how to visualize it? (If so, please edit your question to include a textual description of the database model.) Or do you only have some guidelines so far, and you're having difficulties with deriving a concrete DB model from these? (In that case, please edit your question to show what you have so far and ask about concrete aspects where you're getting stuck (possibly splitting up your question to address unrelated parts separately).)

Comment: I need to draw database model based on this information I had written and I need someone to help me out how to draw it. It can be object or relation model.

Comment: Let me try and summarize: You're generally familiar with the [UML object notation for database schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358774) and [ER diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model), you have designed a database schema (in whichever non-standardized form for now), and you would like to know how to graphically represent the listed aspects in one of the common visual notations for database schemas (or find out whether they are represented in any special way rather than as ordinary columns)?

Comment: Exactly. I tried to search how to draw a database model and this is how I drew it https://ibb.co/4jB6Mbh Does this database model representation make sense to my described database model?

Comment: Aah. It would really help to have that in the question; could you add the graphic there, please? Also, when you write "example columns", do you mean extra columns in the table that simply store example data for the other columns?

Comment: Example columns mean for example CustomerId, First_name, last_name etc..