# Explain SQL query using UML diagram?

Tags: sql, database, plsql, uml, data-modeling

I have to present some complex queries and PL/SQL codes to people who don't know anything about my project. I need to explain how tables are connected, how conditions are affecting the outcome, joins, loops, etc.

Is there a way to document this SQL and PL/SQL logic using UML diagrams?

Comment: Sure you can show tables as (stereotyped) classes with (stereotyped) attributes. But why UML? You could as well use ERD. OR -- Powerpoint :-/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will take a look about your solution. I thought the best way to present that is to do it with an uml diagram. But if there is another solution it would be great!

Comment: Venn Diagrams seem to work too.

Comment: If you provide:
- an example of table
- an example of query
- preferably your attempt so far
the question would be much more valuable (and easier to answer)

Answer (score 6):

Your question is very broad.  Nevertheless some hints:

- Indeed,  you can explain the [data structure with **class diagram**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65965337/3723423).     This allows people to understand how the data is related/connected.  Moreover, it will be very familiar if your audience is object oriented developer.
- You can explain some specific scenarios with example data, using [**object diagrams**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_diagram) that use the above mentioned classes.
- If the PL/SQL code is very complex,  you may use [**activity diagrams**](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-activity-diagram/) to give a visual overview of the processing logic.  Interestingly,  activity diagrams also support [object flows](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/objectflowactivitydiagram.html), which allows to relate the activities to your class model.  However, avoid to go into a detailed retranscription (control flow statement by statement):  activity diagrams are not meant for visual programming, and it would be counter productive in view of the visual complexity.

If you want to know more:

- [an interesting introductory reference](https://web.csulb.edu/colleges/coe/cecs/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=association.php) about mapping UML associations with SQL joins
- [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21282423/3723423) on using class models to document data models, including SQL. There's a link to a nice step by step tutorial for UML->SQL.
- [a short explanation for reverse engineering](https://docs.nomagic.com/display/CDMP190/SQL+to+UML+transformation) for SQL-> UML
- [**great article** from Scott Ambler](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html).  It explains that even [(PL/SQL DML) **triggers**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99888) can be documented in a class diagram, and it provides a ready to use UML profile that allows to use UML stereotypes to highlight some database constructs;

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I don't thnik class diagram or object diagram can help me to explain my queries, because I need to explain the joins, the loops... and I can not do it with such diagrams, may be the activity diagram is the most appropriate one.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. In principle, each join separately is best documented in the class diagram (since the join is about relation, and the associations document such relations).  If it is a join that does not use the primary keys/foreign keys,  you may precede the name of the association with a `/` to express that it's a derived association.    But for loops, or performing several joins in different orders, etc... activity diagram can help.  Apparently there's even a tool to automate diagramming of PL/SQL. I don't know what it's worth: https://umlcode.com (Screenshot is not most convincing)

Comment: @BatmanK I've added a couple of resources, that show how class diagram can be used to document joins and views, and even clarify how some PL/SQL triggers could be highlighted in a class diagram.

Comment: Many thanks, I will take a look at the links